# Working with Images in Xamarin App programmig

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin App compatible with all devices. I have a general question related to images. I am using Location Mark Image Icons to provide locations available on the Map. My issue is, Image has a white background which is also showing along with its background. I want to show only the Image.

Is this related to the designer to provide the image without background? Or as a developer, I can do something on it.

Comment: You need to edit the image (or have the designer do it) to change the background to transparent.

Comment: Unfortunately Jason and mindOfAi are correct. One has to edit the image to get the desired effect. Just wanted to pitch in that making backgrounds transparent is an image editing feature that can be found in many tools. Even PowerPoint's image editing provides a tool for creating transparent backgrounds. So don't look to far for editing you image :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do anything about it using `Xamarin.Forms`. You need to modify the image and remove the background (using Adobe Photoshop, etc.) and make sure to save it as `.png`.

Comment: Thank you mindofAi, I realized that Application has nothing to do with the image.

Answer (score 1):

`Xamarin.Forms` doesn't delete your white background. What you need to do is following a small tutorial on how to use Adobe Photoshop for example and export your images as `png`, you might even consider which `png` type you need, there's 3 types of `png`:

1. `png8`
2. `png24`
3. `png32`

I won't be going deep in explaining each one of them, but you need to know that they all support transparency and could have a transparent background, however, you might notice some differences between them on the edges.
For example, `png8` will give a small white border while `png24` will not show that.
You can check this for example: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/optimizing-images-png-24-format.html

Answer (score 0):

If its simple white background you want to remove, You can utilise simple  `[MakeTransparent][1]` method of`BitMap`.

But this will remove all white coloured pixel. So IF your logo also contains white color, better you contact your designer.